# SSRS Using an IIF expression to set cell Fill Color

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, background-color

I am trying to write a simple IIF statement in Visual Studio to set the color of a cell in Textbox Properties > Fill > Fill Color fx. Can I use an IIF in this situation?

```
=IIF(Fields!TimeImpactRating.Value=0,#00FF00,#000000)
```

When I attempt to run the report, I receive the following error:

> The BackgroundColor for expression for the Textbox TimeImpactRating contains an error: BC31085 Date constant is not valid.

Comment: TimeImpactRating a DateTime column?

Comment: You have to wrap the colors in ""(quotes).  Should be `=IIf(Fields!TimeImpactRating.Value=0,"#00FF00","#000000")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trying to interpret `#00FF00` as a date literal as that is what it most looks like to VBA. The fill color is after a string literal - you need to enclose the color code in double quotes:

```
=IIF(Fields!TimeImpactRating.Value=0, "#00FF00", "#000000")
```